# Decrypt OpenVPN

Tags: безопасность, шифрование, vpn, openvpn

Всем привет!

Друзья, интересует следующий вопрос: предположим, я устанавливаю какой - нибудь бесплатный VPN - клиент от какого - либо сервиса( CyberGhost, WindScribe, ProtonVPN и т.д. ). Все эти клиенты уже идут со встроенными файлами с ключами и сертификатом ( .ovpn, .pem и т.д.).
Вопрос: если я буду использовать такой впн в какой - то сети и кто - то сохранит мой трафик или будет снифферить его в режиме "онлайн", сможет ли он его расшифровать? Имею в виду, что человек может посмотреть, к какому ip идет обращение. По нему вдруг сможет определить, каким именно впн я пользуюсь. Скачает такого же впн - клиента, вытащит оттуда ovpn - файл и  в том же wireshark трафик расшифрует. Такое возможно?

Спасибо за проявленное внимание к вопросу. Хорошего настроения)

Comment: Какой именно впн легко определяется по ip-адресу впн-сервера, а вот касательно ключей добросовестный сервер должен генерировать уникальные ключи для каждого нового пользователя (а вообще по-хорошему генерировать ключ должны лично вы, чтобы его не знал никто кроме вас, чтобы даже сервис его не знал)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что по ip можно определить, бесплатный впн от какого сервиса я использую. К примеру, в том же cyberghost, если подключиться к нему и зайти хоть на 2ip.ru, покажет, что "имя компьюетра": какоето-там_название.cyberghoost.com - это и имел в виду. В ПротонВПН похожее, если выбирать Америку либо Финляндию

Comment: А вообще расшифровать трафик будет невозможно даже со знанием ключа, умные люди в криптографии уже поработали над этим (perfect forward secrecy и всё такое). Но в любом случае у каждого пользователя должен быть свой уникальный ключ